# Multiple WP_Query args combinations according to post type

Tags: wp-query, search, meta-query

I'd like to have separate `meta_query` arguments according to the post type.

For example, I'd like to query `t-shirts` that have a *green collar* or `dress-shirts` that have a *green inner-lining*, right now I only do a single post type check where I check for `t-shirts` *and* `dress-shirts` and I separately check for the meta values which mean that it will also show different combinations such as `t-shirts` that have a *green inner-lining*

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => array('t-shirts', 'dress-shirts'),
    'meta_query' => array(
      'relation' => 'OR',
      array(
        'key' => 'collar',
        'value' => 'green',
      ),
      array(
        'key' => 'inner-lining',
        'value' => 'green',
      )
    ),
));
```

How can I set it up to work with two different args, one if the post type is `t-shirts` and a seperate args if the post type is `dress-shirts` which would look something like:

```
$query = new WP_Query(
  array(
    array(
      'post_type' => array('t-shirts'),
      'meta_query' => array(
        array(
          'key' => 'heal',
          'value' => 'green',
        )
      ),
    ),
    array(
      'post_type' => array('dress-shirts'),
      'meta_query' => array(
        array(
          'key' => 'sleeve',
          'value' => 'green',
        )
      ),
    ),
  )
);
```

Doing two separate queries won't work as it will mess up pagination.

Comment: How many products do you get as a result of such queries? 100/1000/1000000?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż Thousands